# Oracle password expiry and grace period handling using Java, Oracle JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I have an Oracle 11g Database and i´ve coded an application which is along with many other things able to create users. i want the end user who uses the account to change the password after creating so i set the `pasword expire` clause when creating a user.

so now my question is how to handle an `ORA-28001: the password has expired` exception in java, so the user is able to change the password as required. the `grace period`is set to 2 days.

thats the whole error message i get if you need it:

```
    openCon():  URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx:xxxx/dbName username = asd password = mypasswordwhichisexpired
    java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28001: the password has expired

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:600)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:380)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:760)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:401)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at at.nje.DataBaseOp.ConnectOrcl.openCon(ConnectOrcl.java:73)
at at.nje.Kone.GUI.LoginFrame.login(LoginFrame.java:126)
at at.nje.Kone.GUI.LoginFrame$3.actionPerformed(LoginFrame.java:67)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

thanks in advance

EDIT:

here is the code of my openCon() method:

```
    public final Connection openCon(){  
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try{
            System.out.println("openCon():  URL = "+url+" username = "+user+" password = "+ pw);
            prop.setProperty("user", user);
            prop.setProperty("password", pw);
            con = (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,prop); 
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("oracle con ok");            
            return con;
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            String errMessage = e.getMessage();
            System.out.println("oracle con not opened because: "+errMessage);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Login Error", "You shall not pass", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);         
        }
        return null;
}
```

EDIT:
ok thanks i tried this but still getting ora 28001:

```
            public final Connection openCon(){  
    Properties prop = new Properties();
        try{
            System.out.println("openCon():  URL = "+url+" username = "+user+" password = "+ pw);
            prop.setProperty("user", user);
            prop.setProperty("password", pw);
            con = (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,prop); 
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("oracle con ok");            
            return con;
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            String errMessage = e.getMessage();
            System.out.println("oracle con not opened because: "+errMessage);
            EnterNewPwPanel panel = new EnterNewPwPanel();
            if (e.getErrorCode() == 28001) {                    
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, 
                        "Please Enter X and Y Values", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                if(result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
                    String npw = panel.getNewPw();
                    System.out.println("npw: "+npw);

                    prop.setProperty("user", user); // username is correct
                    prop.setProperty("password", pw); // pw is expired but correct
                    prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_SET_NEW_PASSWORD, npw);
                        try {
                            con = (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection (url,prop);
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("setting new pw didnt work after all");
                        }
                }else
                    System.out.println("your pw will expire in x days maddafakka");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Login Error", "You shall not pass", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);   
                //throw(ex);        // for example, just let our caller handle it
            }

        }
        return null;
}
```

after that i get the same error output as i got before

EDIT AGAIN:

well, i thought i had itbut no, didnt work after all, nether the field + new password nor the fields value + new pw worked with this url: 
`static String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.97.10:1521/orcl"`:
not this

```
    prop.setProperty("user", user);
                    prop.setProperty("password", pw);                       
                    prop.setProperty("OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_SET_NEW_PASSWORD", npw);
```

nor this

```
    prop.setProperty("OciNewPassword", npw);
```

Comment: i will read a bit about thin vs thick nowadays i think´ll get the answer i need while researching, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It would have helped if you posted some code. The stack hints about a swing application which starts the oracle connection when you press a button.

So what you do is, in your actionPerformed:

```
try {
    // login to the database
} catch (SqlException ex) {
    if (ex.getErrorCode() == 28001) {
        // do whatever makes sense here, pop up a dialog, ask the user for the new password
    } else {
        // do whatever makes sense if you get a different error code
        throw(ex);        // for example, just let our caller handle it
    }
}
```

To learn how to specify a new password when you set up the Oracle connection, see [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html), especially CONNECTION_PROPERTY_SET_NEW_PASSWORD.

EDIT:

DISCLAIMER: i'm not at a pc right now where i can run a test.

The [DriverManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) class has various different methods of specifying parameters. One of them is the `DriverManager.getConnection(String url, String user, String password)` method that you're using in your above code. There's another one, `DriverManager.getConnection(String url, Properties info)` that allows to pass additional, possibly database-specific properties as well.

You need to put your username and password into a Properties set when using this:

```
java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
info.put ("user", "scott");
info.put ("password","tiger");
con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@",info);
```

Now you can add any of the other documented properties before creating the connection:

```
java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
info.put ("user", "scott");
info.put ("password","tiger");
info.put (OracleDriver.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_SET_NEW_PASSWORD, "gorilla");
con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@",info);
```

which should change the password when you try to login (provided the old one is correct but expired of course).

I found a [hint on the internet](http://www.oracle-java.com/article/4086905/How+to+handle+ORA-28001+error+with+JDBC+thin+driver+?) that the thin driver might not support this and you need the native driver, but that page has no datestamp and the thin driver has gotten a lot of love with version 11, so chances are good this works with the thin driver as well.

Comment: thanks so far, gives me a hint what to do, i additionally posted my opencon() method

Comment: can you tell me how to specify the new password, the information found on the link you posted where really thin(haha) and i couldnt figure out how to actuallly set the new pw

Comment: worth a try and thanks a lot for the fast answer but still getting password expired when i tried to reconn

Comment: Ok - another link (https://community.oracle.com/message/10607895) seems to confirm this needs the oci driver and doesn't work with the thin driver. (The "OciNewPassword" mentioned there is the value of CONNECTION_PROPERTY_SET_NEW_PASSWORD, so this should be ok). But if you're using the OCI driver (your url has "oci", not "thin", between the 2rd and 3nd colon), and it still doesn't work, i'm at my wits end.

Comment: according to this thread it SHOULD work with the thin driver. as 
rp0428 says i only have to change the props 3rd value from CONNECTION_PROPERTY_SET_NEW_PASSWORD to its value OciNewPassword. i´m at work now but i will try this out when i get home, thanks man this could finally be it :D

Comment: and this was always my url: jdbc:oracle:thin...blabla.. so i just have to change the fields name to its value in the prop

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, starting in 12.2 you can use the JDBC-thin driver to change an expired password using the `oracle.jdbc.newPassword` connection property.

Answer (score 0):

// here's some sample code to change an expired password using the Oracle 12.2 jdbc thin driver - ojdbc8.jar

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());


java.util.Properties connInfo = new java.util.Properties();

connInfo.put("user","myuser");

connInfo.put("password","OldPassword");

connInfo.put("database","myhost:1521:mysid");


connInfo.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_NEW_PASSWORD,"NewPassword");


Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@", connInfo);

// password changed

conn.close();
```